# Android studio IDE scripting

Tags: android-studio, scripting

I haven't seen this anywhere else, including in the Android studio help files.

In Android studio, under tools there is an option called 'IDE Scripting Console'. You then get to choose 'script engine' of either ECMAscript or Groovy. What is this used for? Do some power users script coding tasks in Android studio, and if so where could I find out more about this?
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Scripting console is a window in your IDE which allows users to specify commands to the IDE through a console.

For example if you use groovy it is possible to launch a Groovy console for Java projects.

Sample of IDE Scripting

- [Intellij IDE](https://gist.github.com/gregsh/b7ef2e4ebbc4c4c11ee9)
- [Groovy InteractiveConsole](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/launching-groovy-interactive-console.html)

Based on example above I hope you will understand how to run in your Android Studio.

Thanks

Comment: Another resource to learn scripting console concept [here](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Scripting_Console)

Comment: The **run** command for Groovy scripting console is missing from Android Studio.